# Units in a "to" Range

Tags: measuring-units

How should units be written in a phrase like 50-100 (fifty to a hundred).

Would it be 50-100cm or 50cm-100cm?

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: But use an en-dash if you can.

Comment: The en dash _is_ usually used. From Wikipedia: The en dash (–) and en space ( ) are each one en wide. In English, the en dash is commonly used for inclusive ranges (e.g., "pages 12 – 17" or "August 7, 1988 – November 26, 2005"), and increasingly to replace the long dash ("—", also called an em dash). (Note that when using it to replace a long dash, spaces are needed either side of it – like so.)